# Mybatis runs into "Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost" on start up, why?

Tags: java, postgresql, exception, localhost, mybatis

I'm trying a simple mybatis sample code on mac which connects a local postgresql server. I've testing the server connection with my own java jdbc test code, everything works find.

Then my Intellij mybatis maven project is configured with "resources/postgres.properties"

```
jdbc.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
jdbc.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
jdbc.username="postgres"
jdbc.password="password"
```

This is a config that worked for my jdbc test code, and my "resources/mybatis.cfg.xml" is having:

```
<environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:/localhost:5432/postgres" />
            <property name="username" value="postgres" />
            <property name="password" value="password" />
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

Then in my mybatis program, on calling mapper function it gives org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
... 25 more
```

I've searched for a while, all say it's because my /etc/hosts doesn't have localhost configuration. But in fact I have these 2 lines:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

In my intellij environment, I've already done "Project structure->libraries->" to add my postgre driver into my project.

So it doesn't seem to be a localhost configuration problem. Where could be exception came from, how can I troubleshoot and solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: That is clearly a network configuration problem.

Comment: cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
#::1             localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres driver is added into the classpath (org.postgresql.core.PGStream class that appears in the stacktrace belongs to the postgres driver, so it's clearly there).

Now, it can be still a nework issue, as a first resort I suggest to check your program even without mybatis/postgres installation

Try to open a url connection to localhost and some port that is opened for sure) and see what happens right from the "main" method of your application.

You can also try using 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost"

If you see that the localhost is not available, then it is for sure a configuration issue, otherwise other things possible as well.

From your description, it really sounds like a network/configuration issue but since its a "troubleshooting" question, I'm just trying to provide "troubleshooting" ideas...